# Detecting top level frame BHO

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, bho

Sorry for my ignorance. You'll have to explain things to me, I'm treading in new waters. I have some background in JAVA but mostly php, javascript.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19971/How-to-attach-to-Browser-Helper-Object-BHO-with-C

I followed this article with some of my own modifications and my question is specifically, how do I detect the "top level frame" of the webpage, ie the parent document. Any code I execute in `OnDocumentComplete` will run when any iframes on the page have also completed.

My function and the solution I implemented isn't actually producing the correct results.

```
public class BHO:IObjectWithSite
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser;
    HTMLDocument document;

    public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
        string href = document.location.href;

        //get top level page
        if (href == URL.ToString())
        {
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mysite.com");
            WebReq.Method = "POST";
            WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("string");
            WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
            PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            PostData.Close();
            // Prepare web request and send the data.
            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
            StreamReader streamResponse = new StreamReader(WebResp.GetResponseStream(), true);
            string Response = streamResponse.ReadToEnd();

            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject json = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(Response);
            string active = json["active"].ToString();
            //print to screen
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(active, "Title");

        }
    }
```

Checking if `document.location.href` matches `URL` works in most cases but is not guaranteed. So the result is I end up with multiple webrequests and popups on 1 page load.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to store the web browser object (`IWebBrowser2`) in an object property in the `SetSite` method (examples in C++ but should be straightforward to translate to C#):

```
CComQIPtr<IServiceProvider> pServiceProvider(pUnkSite);
if (!pServiceProvider) {
  return E_FAIL;
}

pServiceProvider->QueryService(SID_SWebBrowserApp, IID_IWebBrowser2, (LPVOID*)&m_WebBrowser.p);
if (!m_WebBrowser) {
  return E_FAIL;
}
```

This will store the browser pointer in the object member `m_WebBrowser`. Then you can compare with the `pDisp` parameter to `OnDocumentComplete`:

```
CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> webBrowser(pDisp);
if (webBrowser == m_WebBrowser) {
    // This is the top-level page.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Matthew. How do I use CComQIPtr, what assembly do I have to reference?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc177dxw(v=vs.80).aspx. You just need to include atlcomcli.h.

Comment: Ah but if you're using C# I guess you can just use a normal cast.